# Microsoft SQL find rows where column contains all items in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, search, split

I am trying to find the most efficient way to get the items of an Array that were split and matching it to a column.

for example
Array [mouse, cat, dog]

i need to find a row where column animal has all 3 items (mouse, cat, dog)
i found ways to get if any of those items where found but not all.
i can do it using recursive but its not ideal because i am also going to have to search other columns as well for the same field.

```
declare @Search varchar(100)
set  @Search = 'mouse dog cat'; 

DECLARE @tblWords TABLE( ID int,ArrayValue VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @tblWords (ID, ArrayValue) SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Splitstring] (@Search, ' ')

SELECT   ID, animal ,COUNT(*) as [Result] 
FROM @tblWords
    JOIN zoo 
    on animal like '%' + ArrayValue + '%' 
       GROUP BY  ID, animal
```

this result will find if any of those 3 items found but not all of them.
what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Does column animal contain items such as 'cat mouse dog'? Because that's just... terrible.

Comment: Well,thats one way to learn normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `having` clause to count the number of matches:

```
SELECT z.ID, z.animal, COUNT(*) as [Result] 
FROM @tblWords w JOIN
    zoo z
    on z.animal like '%' + w.ArrayValue + '%' 
GROUP BY z.ID, z.animal
HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from @tblWords);
```

Comment: Hi, it helped but strangely enough i still get a lot of records that has only 1 item. even when the count shows as 2. its incorrect count

Comment: i think the joins are wrong because it shows individual items being searched

Comment: I believe its because the animal column is a large string that has many items. from city, to types of animals, etc.. its a comment field, that doesn't really have a specific separator, could be space or coma. could have comments like  ( owner has a dog and car)   or  (catlover)

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but "bobcat" will match "cat" and "dogfish" will match "dog".  You could have false matches of this type.

Comment: maybe recursive will work better finding out who many items in array, searching for all items?

Comment: @user754975 . . . I don't see how that would make a difference with false matches.  You need smarter logic than the `like` comparison.